# Angular 2 escaping HTML character #

Tags: html, angular

I have HTML code coming from an API as string. I'm displaying the HTML using the below line.

```
<div [innerHTML]="response | safeHtml" class="image-size"></div>
```

In the HTML string, the below line should display '#TOITech'.

```
<a><span style=\"color:rgb(98, 122, 173)\">â€ª#&lrm;</span>TOITechâ€¬</a>
```

But it is displaying as 'â€ª#‎TOITechâ€¬' instead of just '#TOITech'.
How to fix it?

Comment: You should be using `DomSanitizer` and `trustHtml`

Comment: @Aravind I used DOMsanitizer and trustHTML is safeHtml pipe.